# Installing Vector Graphics package produces "The type or namespace 'GradientSettings' could not be found"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity `2019.3.0a6` and am trying to apply SVGs to game objects. I installed the Vector Graphics preview package and I see an error in the console after doing so:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0.0-preview.4\Runtime\InternalBridge\VectorImageBridge.cs(206,64): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GradientSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've googled this error in vain, as it comes up with pretty much nothing. It seems like I'm running a very recent build (June 2019) so I doubt that I need an upgrade. I've tried dragging my SVGs into the scene but I'm not able to, probably because of this error. I'm somewhat new to Unity, so if there are some logs I can check for more detailed information, please let me know.

Comment: Good point. I tried installing Vector Graphics on 1.11 and I get no errors, so I think that's the solution. Go ahead and post it as a full answer and I will mark solved - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity `2019.3.0a6` is an **Alpha** version.

**Don't use alpha versions** for production. They are not stable and full of bugs and errors. You should only use them for testing the absolutely newest features .. and **only** for that. That's the whole purpose of having alpha and beta versions.

---

Rather stick to the latest **stable** versions! Currently it is [`2019.1.11`](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/whats-new/2019.1.11)

Comment: Thanks. What's weird is, if I try updating to `2019.1.11f1`, Unity Hub asks me to confirm that I want to *downgrade* my project... yet, alpha 6 is dated June 19th and 1.11 is dated July 19th.

Comment: yes but the release is `2019.3` vs `2019.1` so you are downgrading ;)